# Sequelize Not showing all unique violation errors

Tags: node.js, postgresql, validation, error-handling, sequelize.js

In my application, a user must have a unique username and email and While using Sequelize I noticed that Sequelize only throws one unique violation even though both of the fields have a duplicate username and email.
[image: First Time adding unique data returns with 200 status]

[image: Trying to send the same data throws unique violation with status 400]

But the problem with the unique violation thrown is that both emailOrPhone and username have violated the unique violation but the error only shows one.

My User Model:

```
  User.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      emailOrPhone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Email address or phone number is already in use',
        },
        validate: {
          notEmpty: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Email or phone is required',
          },
        },
      },
      userName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Username is already taken',
        },
        validate: {
          notEmpty: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Username is required',
          },
        },
      },
      fullName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Name is required',
          },
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Password Field is required',
          },
        },
      },
      profilePicture: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        notEmpty: true,
        defaultValue: path.resolve('profile.jpg'),
      },
      roles: {
        type: DataTypes.JSON,
        defaultValue: ['user'],
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize: Sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
```

So my question is that is there any way to show both the unique violation error fields.